# wpp.targets file is ignored when publishing website from Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2019, web-deployment

I have added my existing website (a small home site for learning) running off my local network server (Server 2019) to Visual Studio 2019. When I publish the site from my dev machine to my local server the wpp.targets file is ignored and deploys items I have selected in the file to not be pushed. It is pushed via a shared folder from the server.

I'm new to VS or connecting it to a server but when I search for this topic I see a few things:

1. The Projectname.wpp.targets folder should be in the root directory, which it is
2. Most things I've read talk about the .csproj, .vbproj, etc files, which I do not have in my project

I'm at a loss on what the correct solution is as I'm fairly certain the file is correct, I'll post it below, I hope someone can point me in the right direction. And forgive me, I'm very new to this but I'm doing my best to learn, I'm not a professional in this regard.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="Internal">
            <FromTarget>MTGDeckSource.wpp.targets</FromTarget>
        </ExcludeFromPackageFiles>
        <ExcludeFromPackageFolders Include="Internal">
            <FromTarget>img\card_images\*</FromTarget>
        </ExcludeFromPackageFolders>
        <ExcludeFromPackageFolders Include="Internal">
            <FromTarget>css\bulma\css\*</FromTarget>
        </ExcludeFromPackageFolders>
        <ExcludeFromPackageFolders Include="Internal">
            <FromTarget>App_Data\*</FromTarget>
        </ExcludeFromPackageFolders>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Here is the same question as a reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54593430/wpp-targets-is-ignored-when-publishing-a-clean-solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54593430/wpp-targets-is-ignored-when-publishing-a-clean-solution).

Comment: It's not the same question, I noted the differences in the projects, I also tried one of those possible answers by restarting VS2019 and nothing changed.

Comment: mab be you can try to import the wpp.targets files in the project.